# How to access the first character of a character array?

Tags: c, arrays, indexing, printf, character

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char x [] = "hello world.";
    printf("%s \n", &x[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code prints out `"hello world."`

How would i print out just `"h"`? Shouldn't the access `x[0]` ensure this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should do:

```
printf("%c \n", x[0]);
```

The [format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) to print a char is `c`. So the format string to be used is `%c`.

Also to access an array element at a valid index `i` you need to say `array_name[i]`. You should not be using the `&`. Using `&` will give you the address of the element.

Answer (score 6):

> Shouldn't the access `x[0]` ensure this?

No, because the `&` in `&x[0]` gets the address of the first element of the string (so it's equivalent to just using `x`.

`%s` will output all the characters in a string sees the null character at the end of the string (which is implicit for literal strings).

In order to print out a character rather than the whole string, use the character format specifier, `%c` instead.

Note that `printf("%s \n", x[0]);` would be invalid since `x[0]` is of type `char` and `%s` expects a `char *`.

Comment: @Kay, instead of posting a comment saying "Many thanks", try clicking the up-arrow beside the post.  Also, click the checkmark beside whichever one is the best answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char x [] = "hello world.";
    printf("%c \n", x[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A string in C is an array of characters with the last character being the NULL character `\0`. When you use the `%s` string specifier in a `printf`, it will start printing chars at the given address, and continue until it hits a null character. To print a single character use the `%c` format string instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since a string in C is an array of characters.
This statement will print the first character.

```
printf("%c \n", "hello world."[0]);
```